# Php if up to an amount

Tags: php, mysql, row

I am trying to use an if statement to increase a db row ($row[`cost`]) 20% up to but not including a different row.  As of now my code is: $row-->cost/.80 so I basically want it to not hit the maximumbid which is held in this query:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT bp.*, b.company
FROM `windows_brands_products` bp 
LEFT JOIN `windows_brands` b 
ON bp.brand_id = b.id 
JOIN Windows_last_submissions ls
JOIN windows_materials wm
WHERE ls.username = '$current_user->user_login'
AND bp.width = ROUND(ls.width) 
AND bp.height = ROUND(ls.height) 
AND bp.material IN (wm.name) 
AND bp.type = ls.type 
AND IF (ls.minimumbid != '0.00',bp.cost BETWEEN ls.minimumbid 
AND ls.maximumbid,bp.cost <= ls.maximumbid)
ORDER BY b.company ASC");
```

Question being how do I reference row minimumbid so I can prevent this 80%increase from hitting maximumbid?